# ESP32 thinks I am dereferencing a NULL pointer

Tags: c, embedded, esp32, esp-idf

*Edited to add information

I am making an embedded application on the ESP-WROOM-32 and I have run into an issue. The program runs into a StoreProhibited error which means that it tried to dereference a NULL pointer. I have a double pointer in a struct that I want to point to the first element in a double array, but whenever I try to do this, it throws the error. What makes even less sense, is that when I point a regular double pointer (not in a struct) to the double array, the code works fine.

Here is the struct:

```
struct emxArray_real_T {
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};
```

Here is the pointer declaration/initialization:

```
emxArray_real_T *Timeptr = 0;
emxArray_real_T Time;
emxArray_real_T *gFzptr = 0;
emxArray_real_T gFz;
double *gFzptrOG; 

void FFTarraysInit(void){
    
    Timeptr = malloc(sizeof(Time));
    gFzptr = malloc(sizeof(gFz));

    

    Timeptr->data = calloc(4000, sizeof(double));   
    gFzptr->data = calloc(4000, sizeof(double));

    Timeptr->size = malloc(sizeof(*Timeptr->size)*4000);
    gFzptr->size = malloc(sizeof(*gFzptr->size)*4000);

    //emxInit_real_T(&Timeptr, Timeptr->numDimensions);
    //emxInit_real_T(&gFzptr, gFzptr->numDimensions);

    Timeptr->size[0] = 4000;
    gFzptr->size[0] = 4000;

    gFzptrOG = gFzptr->data; 

    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

Here is the declaration of the zData array which takes data from an accelerometer and stores it as doubles:

```
double zData[4000];
```

Here is the line that throws an error:

```
 gFzptrOG = &zData[0];       // gFzptrOG is a double pointer, zData[] is an array of doubles
 gFzptr->data = gFzptrOG;    // This line throws the error
```

I also print the values of &zData[0] and gFzptrOG just to make sure they are the same after equating them. gFzptrOG is a double pointer that is not necessary for the program, but just to make sure that zData has a valid address. They print the same value address when I comment out the line that throws the error.

Apparently, the gFzptr struct pointer is invalid, but I do not know how to make it valid. I am new to memory allocation so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `gFzptr` is *actually* NULL.  A [mcve] would help us check this for you.  Or at least showing the lines that define `gFzptr` and make it point to a valid location.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am printing &zData[0] and gFzptrOG right before the lines I posted and they equal each other and neither of them are NULL. Example print: Data Collected: 0x3ffb29d0
 0x3ffb29d0

Comment: As far as I know `gFzptr` and `gFzptrOG` are different identifiers (only one of them ends in `OG`).  You still need to make sure `gFzptr` is a valid pointer.

Comment: *Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am printing &zData[0] and gFzptrOG right before the lines I posted and they equal each other and neither of them are NULL.*  Stop describing your code and post it as part of the question.

Comment: You should really check to see if `malloc()` and `calloc()` failed.

Comment: As an aside, you assign `gFzptr->data` to a dynamically allocated block, then later reassign with something else - what happens to the original block? In the fragment at least, it looks like a potential memory leak.

Comment: The magic numbers (4000) are ill-advised also.  It is entirely likely that you are seeing the result of some earlier error or data corruption that is caused by code not shown.  If this fragment is indicative of the code quality in general, that is perhaps not surprising.

Comment: You might do well design-wise to create a sub structure containing `int data; `int size;` then a single `callioc` of 4000 such structures.  But only if both are intended to to be accessed together.

Comment: BTW how do you know the error is thrown at that specific line? Clearly you have debug information not shown in the question.  If information you have used to draw that conclusion should be included in the question.  It is possible that you are misinterpreting that evidence.

Comment: The insrtance `gFz` is unused other than to take its size,  and for that you don't need an instance, just `gFzptr = malloc(sizeof(*gFzptr));` or use the `gFx` instance rather then dynamically allocating a second instance:  `gFz.data = calloc(4000, sizeof(*gFz.data));`.  Frankly though, this is just weird code.  Ill-advised dynamic memory allocation, [global data](https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/), and what is that task deletion for!?  Are you instantiating a task just to allocate global data and die?  That is an insane use of resource and a recipe for all sorts of race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The only dereference in the code fragment shown is the member access `gFzptr->data`.  Clearly `gFzptr` is not a valid pointer -even if you believe otherwise.

Before the assignment add a check such as:

```
assert( gFzptr != NULL ) ;
```

or

```
if( gFzptr == NULL )
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Here is the declaration and initialization: `emxArray_real_T *gFzptr;` `emxArray_real_T gFz;` `gFzptr = malloc(sizeof(gFz));` `gFzptr->data = calloc(4000, sizeof(double));` I am pretty new to memory allocation so I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: That I formation is now in the question; no need to repeat it in a comment.

Comment: Actually, you define a pointer `gFzPtr` and right in the next line a variable `gFz` .. why do you use now `gFzPtr = malloc(sizeof(gFz);`, instead of just let gFzPtr point to that gFz by assigning it like `gFzPtr = &gFz; ` ?

Comment: @kesselhaus : I think your comment belongs against the question, not this answer.  But you are right it is weird code.

Comment: @Clifford, sorry, it was actually meant to Alecs comment  of your answer, but seem to have forgotten the "@Alec"